# Convert string time to unix time and vice versa

Tags: c++, unix-timestamp

I have been trying to simply convert a string "1998-04-11" to a UNIX timestamp which should be 892245600 according to an online converter.

But I keep getting a different result.

```
    struct tm tm;
    time_t ts;

    strptime("1998-04-11", "%Y-%m-%d", &tm);
    tm.tm_mon = tm.tm_mon -1;
    ts = mktime(&tm);

    printf("%d \n", (int)ts); //unix time-stamp
    printf("%s \n", ctime(&ts)); //human readable date
```

Result:

```
893502901
Sat Apr 25 13:15:01 1998
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: using same time zone in online converter and your local machine ?

Comment: How do I check that? Also how am I getting a totally different date from what I inputted? Does that have to do with the local time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zero the `tm` structure before calling `strptime`

```
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
```

From the notes section at: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html

> In principle, this function does not initialize `tm` but stores only
>   the values specified.  This means that `tm` should be initialized
>   before the call.

And `memset` is used as above in the example from the same page.

Comment: This works. And I don't have to use `tm.tm_mon = tm.tm_mon -1;`
 anymore. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem of uninitialized memory.

```
(gdb) p tm
$1 = {tm_sec = 1, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 4196061, tm_mday = 0, tm_mon = -5984, tm_year = 32767, 
tm_wday = 0, tm_yday = 0, tm_isdst = 4195984, tm_gmtoff = 4195616, 
tm_zone = 0x7fffffffe980 "\001"}
```

As you can see in the debugger, `struct tm` has random memory assigned.  Making the time_zone offset garbage.

After `strptime` runs:

```
(gdb) p tm
$3 = {tm_sec = 1, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 4196061, tm_mday = 11, tm_mon = 3, tm_year = 98, 
tm_wday = 6, tm_yday = 100, tm_isdst = 4195984, tm_gmtoff = 4195616, 
tm_zone = 0x7fffffffe980 "\001"}
```

In addition the:

```
tm.tm_mon = tm.tm_mon -1;
```

Is unnecessary.  Corrected code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

struct tm tm;
time_t ts = 0;
memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(tm));

    strptime("1998-04-11", "%Y-%m-%d", &tm);
    ts = mktime(&tm);

    printf("%d \n", (int)ts); //unix time-stamp
    printf("%s \n", ctime(&ts)); //human readable date
}
```

Output:

```
892252800
Sat Apr 11 00:00:00 1998
```

Comment: Thank you this is a great explanation to understand the process better.